# Why user-unhandled exceptions checkboxes are disabled in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

On my `VS2010` **Debug**->**exceptions** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>E)</kbd> the checkboxes on the user-unhandled exception column are disabled but for `CLR Exceptions`.
On my `VS2008` they are enabled for all the lines.
So in `VS2010` I can't ignore a user defined exception.
Any idea how can I enable them like I have on `VS2008`.
On other machines with `VS2010` I've seen it's enabled so it's something with my installation settings.